# How to center a DIV popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to centre a DIV which contains a form.  I have managed to grey out the back ground and would like to centre the form within the window.  Below is what I have done so far, but I do not know how to progress it further to get the result that I need.

I am able to 'auto margin' horizontally, but I am not able to do this vertically (please see image).  If you stretch the browser window further vertically, the form stretches to occupy all of the vertically space.

[image]

```
 #idOfForm{
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 10000;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 500px;
 min-height: 250px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #b8b8b8;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #484848;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can center elements easily:

Suppose you have the following:

```
<div class="aaa">
    fsdfsd
</div>
```

Use the following css:

```
.aaa {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
 }
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ffnvjz4q/
This is the code you need:

```
#idOfForm{
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    z-index: 10000;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #b8b8b8;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #484848;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What browsers does your 'app' must support ? The easiest way to achieve this is using CSS flexbox but it is not fully support yet

http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px; /* Or whatever */
}

.child {
  width: 100px;  /* Or whatever */
  height: 100px; /* Or whatever */
  margin: auto;  /* Magic! */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="modal">
 <div class="modal-body">
  <!-----put your form code here --->
 </div>
</div>


.modal {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 z-index: 2;
}

.modal-body {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 50px auto 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 min-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Source: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/